# How can I check how many words in common two strings have in Bigquery?

Tags: string-comparison, google-bigquery

I have a list of documents in a Bigquery table. Some of those have very similar names. I need to check each pair of documents, and see how many words they have in common, so I can suggest eliminating one of those.

For instance:

```
 Spreadsheets
 Quality Control.xlsx
 Product Structure.xlsx
 Invoices Sent April.xslx
 Invoices Sent March.xlsx
 Total Costs April.xlsx
 Total Costs March.xlsx
 Process of Quality Control.xlsx`
```

I would have the result like

```
 Spreadsheet                        |Matching Spreadsheet             |Words
 Quality Control.xlsx               |Process of Quality Control.xlsx  |2
 Product Structure.xlsx             |null                             |null
 Invoices Sent April.xslx           |Invoices Sent March.xlsx         |2
 Invoices Sent March.xlsx           |Invoices Sent April.xlsx         |2
 Total Costs April.xlsx             |Total Costs March.xlsx           |2
 Total Costs March.xlsx             |Total Costs April.xlsx           |2
 Process of Quality Control.xlsx    |Quality Control.xlsx             |2
```

Comment: you should provide more details!

Comment: Just updated the description. Hope my question is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.spreadsheets`  AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Quality Control.xlsx' AS spreadsheet UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Product Structure.xlsx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Invoices Sent April.xslx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Invoices Sent March.xlsx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Total Costs April.xlsx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Total Costs March.xlsx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'Process of Quality Control.xlsx' 
)
SELECT 
  id, s1 spreadsheet, IF(words = 0, NULL, s2) matching_spreadsheet, words 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, s1,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(s2, words) ORDER BY words DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.spreadsheet s1, t2.spreadsheet s2,
      ( SELECT COUNTIF(word != 'xlsx') 
        FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(t1.spreadsheet, r'\w+')) word
        JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(t2.spreadsheet, r'\w+')) word
        USING(word)) words
    FROM `project.dataset.spreadsheets` t1
    CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.spreadsheets` t2
    WHERE t1.spreadsheet != t2.spreadsheet
  )
  GROUP BY id, s1
)
-- ORDER BY id
```

with result as

```sql
Row id  spreadsheet                     matching_spreadsheet            words
1   1   Quality Control.xlsx            Process of Quality Control.xlsx 2
2   2   Product Structure.xlsx          null                            0
3   3   Invoices Sent April.xslx        Invoices Sent March.xlsx        2
4   4   Invoices Sent March.xlsx        Invoices Sent April.xslx        2
5   5   Total Costs April.xlsx          Total Costs March.xlsx          2 
6   6   Total Costs March.xlsx          Total Costs April.xlsx          2
7   7   Process of Quality Control.xlsx Quality Control.xlsx            2
```